# Zero trace Sobolev space on Carnot group

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, lie-groups, sobolev-spaces

Let $\mathbb{G}=(\mathbb{R}^{n},\circ)$ be a Lie group on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ be the corresponding Lie algebra of  $\mathbb{G}$.  Let $X_{1},\ldots,X_{m}$ be the left invariant vector fields on $\mathbb{G}$ such that $X_{k}(0)=\partial_{x_{k}}|_{0}$ for $k=1,\ldots,m$ and
$$ \mathrm{Lie}(X_{1},\ldots,X_{m})=\mathfrak{g}$$

Consider the Sobolev space
$$ H_{X}^{1}(\mathbb{G}):=\{ u\in L^2(\mathbb{G})| X_{j}u\in L^2(\mathbb{G}),~1\leq j\leq m\}. $$
It is known that $H_{X}^{1}(\mathbb{G})$ is a Hilbert space endowed with the norm
$$ \|u\|_{H_{X}^{1}(\mathbb{G})}^{2}:=\|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{G})}^{2}+\|Xu\|_{L^2(\mathbb{G})}^{2}=\|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{G})}^{2}+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\|X_{j}u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{G})}^{2}.$$
Suppose that  $\Omega\subset \mathbb{G}$ is a bounded open set with continuous boundary $\partial\Omega$, we denote by $H_{X,0}^{1}(\Omega)$ the closure of $C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in $H_{X}^{1}(\mathbb{G})$, which is also a Hilbert space.

**Question:** Can we characterize $H_{X,0}^{1}(\Omega)$ by
$$ H_{X,0}^{1}(\Omega)=\{u\in H_{X}^{1}(\mathbb{G})|u=0~~\mbox{a.e}~\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega\}=\{u\in H_{X}^{1}(\mathbb{G})|\text{supp}~u\in \overline{\Omega}\} ? $$

**Comments:**
In classical case, a result by

*Chandler-Wilde, S. N.; Hewett, D. P.; Moiola, A.*, [**Sobolev spaces on non-Lipschitz subsets of (\mathbb {R}^n) with application to boundary integral equations on fractal screens**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00020-017-2342-5), Integral Equations Oper. Theory 87, No. 2, 179-224 (2017). [ZBL1373.46024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1373.46024). shows  that $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)=\{u\in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)|u=0~~\mbox{a.e}~\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega\}=\{u\in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)|\text{supp}~u\in \overline{\Omega}\}$ provided that $\partial\Omega$ is continuous, but I wonder this result is valid for the weighted Sobolev space $H_{X,0}^{1}(\Omega)$ on Carnot group.